# Executing bad excess on receiving a function return array?

Tags: arrays, function, swift2, return-value, swift-playground

What is the problem with the following function to receive and execute:

```
 func FibFast(num: Int) -> Array<Int> {
        var fib_arr = [Int](num)
        if num < 1 {
            fib_arr[0] = 0
            return fib_arr
        } else if num < 2 {
            fib_arr[1] = 1
            return fib_arr
        }else {
            for var i = 2; i < num; i++ {
                fib_arr[i] = fib_arr[i-1] + fib_arr[i-2]
            }
            return fib_arr
        }
    }
```

when I am trying to receive the array like:

```
var newArray = FibFast(10)
```

it's producing a bad execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to subscript the array with indexes that don't exist, similarly in your else case you are trying to subscript to an index of 2 when the array is empty.

the line `var fib_arr = [Int]()` creates an empty array on integers. when you use `fib_arr[0] = 0` you are trying to assign the value at index 0 to have a value of 0 but no value currently exists. I would recommend using the `append(_)` method ie. `fib_arr.append(0)`.

Also when you pass in a value of 10 or anything that is 2 or more as the `num` parameter your `if-else if-else` statement is executing the for loop where you are attempting to access the index of `0` and `1` which have not been set as the earlier statements were never executed as they were skipped by the `if-else if-else` block.

The for loop and assign the values with subscripts is very indicative of the fact that you've probably learnt a different language before swift. You should note that the classic c-style for loop you are trying to use will be removed from swift soon so its better to get in the habbit of no using it. Ive rewritten your code as close to the way you wrote yours, please don't hesitate to ask if you have any questions about it.

```
func fib(num: Int) -> [Int] {
  var fib_arr = [Int]()
  if num == 0 {
    fib_arr.append(0)
  } else if num == 1 {
    fib_arr.append(0)
    fib_arr.append(1)
  } else {
    fib_arr = [0, 1]
    for i in 2..<num {
      fib_arr.append(fib_arr[i - 1] + fib_arr[i - 2])
    }
  }
  return fib_arr
}
```

Comment: what if I add an arrayLiteral like
var fib_arr = [Int](arrrayLiteral: num) ? is it not allocate memory for the array?

Comment: `var fib_arr = [Int](arrrayLiteral: num)` will create an array with only one element being num ie. `[num]`

Answer (score 1):

The answer proposed by Blake Lockley can also be coded like this:

```
func FibFast(num: Int) -> Array<Int> {
    var fib_arr = [Int]()   // empty array
    if num < 1 {
        fib_arr += [0]      // add element [0]
        return fib_arr
    } else if num < 2 {
        fib_arr += [0]      // add element [0]
        fib_arr += [1]      // add element [1]
        return fib_arr
    }else {
        fib_arr = [0, 1]    // init with [0, 1]
        for var i = 2; i < num; i++ {
            // add computed element
            fib_arr += [fib_arr[i-1] + fib_arr[i-2]]
        }
        return fib_arr
    }
}
```